# Installing OpenCV in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, openssl, spyder, anaconda3

I am trying to install openCV in spyder through anaconda prompt, but I keep getting the same error. I have tried a few solutions but nothing helped.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvnTo.png)

```
(base) C:\Users\11919>conda install -c conda-forge opencv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
```

Here is my conda info[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh54R.png)

```
(base) C:\Users\11919>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\11919\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\11919\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\11919\.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : 3.22.0
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __win=0=0
       base environment : C:\Users\11919\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\11919\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\11919\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\11919\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\11919\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\11919\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\11919\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\11919\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.9.13 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19044
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

. I did try to copy these tow files from library/bin to DLL
libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Comment: Please share your errors inside a code block not images.

Comment: The `Solving environment` step can sometimes take many minutes, how long did you leave it before deciding this was an error? However you would probably do better to [create a new environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) with opencv and any other packages you want to use for this specific project.

Comment: It did take a lot of time, but at the end this was an error, I tried to create a new environment too but that failed as well, was getting the same error